# How to call custom endpoints with token on SAP Spartacus storefront?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm new on SAP Spartacus storefront, and I'm trying to make a custom API call to check if CNPJ is valid on customer database.
My backend is ready and needs to receive a Token on request header.

But I don't find on Spartacus documentation how to use a default token service or interceptor to make this call.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks for your time, have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Spartacus Session Management](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/session-management/) documentation.

- If you need to send the user token, by default it is included in the
  header of every request made to "occ". This means that if you want to
  have this same behavior for an endpoint not in OCC you will need to
  extend and overwrite `AuthHttpHeaderService` more specifically the
  `isOccUrl` method so that it returns "true" for occ endpoints and
  your external endpoints. It will look like this:

```
[...]
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CustomAuthHttpHeaderService extends AuthHttpHeaderService {
  constructor(
    protected authService: AuthService,
    protected authStorageService: AuthStorageService,
    protected oAuthLibWrapperService: OAuthLibWrapperService,
    protected routingService: RoutingService,
    protected occEndpoints: OccEndpointsService,
    protected globalMessageService: GlobalMessageService
  ) {
   super(...);
   }

   protected isOccUrl(url: string): boolean {
    return url.includes(this.occEndpoints.getBaseUrl()) || url === 'my-custom-url';
  }
}
```

And for the injection:

```
{
 provide: AuthHttpHeaderService,
 useClass: CustomAuthHttpHeaderService
}
```

- If you need the client token you simply need to place the following
  string `'cx-use-client-token'` in your request's header. If it's
  there and the user is anonymous, the `ClientTokenInterceptor` will
  add the client token. It should be used as follow:

```
[...]

let headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
});
headers = InterceptorUtil.createHeader(USE_CLIENT_TOKEN, true, headers);

// Your request
return this.http.post('/your-request-endpoints', { headers });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the both solutions is not working for me.
I tryed to use the `cx-use-client-token` but in request i got `Autorization: cx-use-client-token`
And in CustomAuthHttpHeaderService my `createAuthorizationHeader` function is returning {}

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It seems you are trying to use the client token since the `createAuthorizationHeader` function will return `{}` if no token is available (user is anonymous). I updated my answer with an example to explain how to use the client token.

Comment: Nice, maybe the problem is my spartacus version, i'm using v3.2, i'm downloaded the v3.3 in separated project and the `USE_CLIENT_TOKEN` is working.
I will upgrade my spartacus version to fix that.

Comment: Upgraded my spartacus version, is working now. Thanks for your time.